# What does constraints on inputs in UI5 do?

Tags: sapui5

I have implemented no alphanumeric constraints on ui5 input but for some reason I am able to enter non-alphanumeric values. Here is my code

```
<Input id="ID" type="Text" width="25%" placeholder="some text"
value="{path: '', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String', constraints: {search: '^[a-zA-Z0-9 .]+$'}}"/>
```

I am able to enter characters like {}. Am I misunderstanding constraints.
The expected result is an input field with only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: If the below answer was helpful, consider to accept the answer as a solution. See _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 1):

According to [API reference of `sap.ui.model.type.String`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.type.String#constructor):.

> Constraints; #validateValue throws an error if any constraint is violated.

If any constraint is violated, a [`validationError`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#events/validationError) will be triggered.

```xml
<Input
    validationError=".onValidationError"
    value="{
        path: 'myPath',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
        constraints: {
            // some constraints..
        }
    }"
/>
```

```js
onValidationError: function(oEvent) {
    const oInput = oEvent.getSource();
    oInput.setValueState("Error");
    oInput.setValueStateText(oEvent.getParameter("message"));
    oInput.setValue(oEvent.getParameter("oldValue")); // if you want to revert the wrong input additionally.
},
```

**Or** let framework [handle valueStates and messages automatically](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7#section_w2c_jmj_rhb) by adding `handleValidation` to the app descriptor. No need to listen to `validationError`.

```json
"sap.ui5": {
    "handleValidation": true,
    "...": "..."
}
```

So having *`constraints`* does **not** prevent users from entering invalid values in the UI. It does, however, prevent the invalid value from being stored in the model (assuming the property is two-way bound).

If the user has to enter a specific Serial Number/Product Activation Key/ISBN, use [`sap.m.MaskInput`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.MaskInput/sample/sap.m.sample.MaskInput).

Not your question but this may be interesting for you:

- [Message Handling - Fiori Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/messaging/)
- [Error, Warning and Info Messages](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/62b1481d3e084cb49dd30956d183c6a0)
- [Message Manager samples](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.ui.core.message.MessageManager)